# popover is not refreshing on table row clicked

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, bootstrap-5

I have a table and a button. On button/anchor tag clicked, I need to display content of selected table row data.

Here is JSFiddle

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
  
  $('#popanch').popover({
                html: true,
                content: function () {
                    var content = "";
                    content = displayProj();
                    alert(content);
                    return content;
                },
                title: '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>'
            });
  
  });
   
        
         function displayProj() {
            var rows = $('#tblGrid tbody tr.selected').find("td:eq(0)").data('value') || 0;
            if (rows > 0) {
                var tabrowselected = $('#tblGrid tbody tr.selected');
                var createdby = $(tabrowselected).find("td:eq(0)").data('creator');
               
              

                var contentHTML = '<div>' +
                    '<div class="media-body">' +
                    '<div id="popoverData">' +
                    '<span class="red">Created By: </span> ' + createdby + '<br/>' +
                  
                    '</div></div></div>';

                return contentHTML;
            }
            else {
                var contentHTML = '<div>' +
                    '<div class="media-body">' +
                    '<div id="popoverData"> Please select any Project</div>' +
                    '</div></div>';
                return contentHTML;
            }
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vrnfcp4e/5/

Answer (score 0):

I could able to solve this

```
$(document).on("click", ".popover .close", function () {
            $('#popanch').popover('dispose'); //instead of hide, dispose
            
        });
```

and

```
$("#popanch").on("click", function () {
               
                $('#popanch').popover({
                    html: true,
                    content: function () {
                        var content = displayProj();
                        
                        return content;
                    },
                    title: '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>'
                }).popover('show'); //this line added
            });
```